# Remove Databases from HA Group using TSQL - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, high-availability, sql-server-2022

I am trying to automate following steps using TSQL (It is currently working fine using Manual -GUI interface of SQLServer), working on **SQLServer 2022**

1. Create a table, with columns to store DBName, AGName, Database_onAG, Database_Not_onAG. **(COMPLETE)**
2. Write a stored proc script to get the list of all AvailabilityGroups, DB's on AG, then load the result into the table created in step 1. **(COMPLETE)**
3. Script should remove the DBS with any name starting with logdb% from AG **(PROBLEM)**
   TSQL to Remove:

> ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP @AGName REMOVE DATABASE @DBName

**I need help with the above TSql command, it executes without any error but DB doesn't remove from AG. It still keeps on showing in the AG group. How to Perform this step using TSql please?**

4. Then we add the DBs to the AG, and the script should sync the databases that we stored in the new table. (Please recommend any TSQL command to Sync between two same databases stored in the Same DB instance or separately)

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: I don't have a setup to test, but, I don't think you can use variables for AG name and db name.  Have you tried with dynamic SQL?

Comment: I have written the Dynamic SQL. i.e. using Cursor. It executes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: ALTER DATABASE database_name SET HADR OFF
I have found it in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/remove-a-secondary-database-from-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16